# Making a div straddle two adjacent divs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a button that would straddle two divs vertically one on top of the other. This button is in the form of a round div with a downward-facing chevron character inside it (using Font Awesome). Clicking this button would serve to scroll the page down to a predesignated point within the same page. This feature is very common in many modern single-page designs. Here's my attempt:

```css
.aboutjumbo {
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}
.aboutjumbo p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.downarrow {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  margin-bottom: -5.5em;
}
.downarrow i {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.test {
  height: 12em;
  background-color: #a5a5a5;
  z-index: -20;
  margin-top: -2em;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- about.html -->
  <div class="jumbotron text-center top-jumbotron aboutjumbo">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>About Us</h1>
      <p>Know all about one of the most vibrant rendezvous for Spanish self-learners around the world.</p>
      <div class="downarrow text-center"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="test">
    <p>blah blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see, I am unable to achieve the desired effect of the scroll button (the round red div) straddling both divs. Instead, the lower half is getting eaten up by the second div despite the assigned z-index values. Also, I am unable to center the button horizontally. Can someone help me fix it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the `z-index` property only applies to *positioned* elements.

Therefore you simply need to add `position: relative` to the `.downarrow` element.

Of course, `position: absolute`/`position: fixed` would *position* the element as well, but relative positioning will keep the element in the document flow, which is likely what you want.

```
.downarrow {
    /* ... */
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    margin-bottom: -5.5em;
}
```

Updated Example:

```css
.aboutjumbo {
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}
.aboutjumbo p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.downarrow {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  margin-bottom: -5.5em;
}
.downarrow i {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.test {
  height: 12em;
  background-color: #a5a5a5;
  z-index: -20;
  margin-top: -2em;
}

.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
}
.downarrow {  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2em;
  left: 0; right:0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- about.html -->
  <div class="jumbotron text-center top-jumbotron aboutjumbo">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>About Us</h1>
      <p>Know all about one of the most vibrant rendezvous for Spanish self-learners around the world.</p>
      <div class="downarrow text-center"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="test">
    <p>blah blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. I knew it had to be something stupid on my part. And how do you suggest I center the red div horizontally?

Comment: @TheLearner See the CSS added at the bottom of this example - https://jsfiddle.net/duox5x24/